# Set relative root in subfolder with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, jekyll

I have a very large website deployed with Jekyll. I want to upload it in my server inside a subfolder called **`project`**, but every link and asset url in this project starts with **`"/"`**.

So, I want to set **`domain.com/project`** as **`"root"`** only for the files uploaded in **`project`**. Working like this:

**Current**

```
Relative url            Absolute url
"/assets/etc.."         "domain.com/assets/etc..".
```

**Desired**

```
Relative url            Absolute url
"/assets/etc.."         "domain.com/project/assets/etc.."
```

Is this possible with .htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

So you mean effectively host the website project off of `http://domain.com/project/`? So the "site" is a directory of another "site" (though really one site)?

That seems like a github type situation.

In your config file, set `baseurl` to `/project` (maybe no `/`).

When you are referencing your urls, use something like:

`{{page.url | prepend: site.baseurl | prepend: site.url }}`

Another way may even be to simply set `url` to `http://domain.com/project`?

There may even be an updated way to do this with recent changes. So check the docs too.

Hope I understood you right, and have fun!